# Loading in Multiple Excel Files using readmatrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have this short code below but I am trying to import 5 excel files, names 101, 102, 103, 104 and 105.xlsx into matlab's workspace as separate cells so i can later make figures by calling on a column in each cell array.

They have the same number of columns (BS:BX) 6 columns is all I need but will have various rows. I'm new to MATLAB so maybe I am missing something easy here, it doesn't like the line "filename = (k,'%dtrf.xlsx');". "Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters."

```
clear all

close all

mkdir myfolder

dir myfolder

for k = 101 : 105

filename = (k,'*.xlsx');

data = readmatrix(strcat(filename),'Range','BS:BX');

end
```

Comment: Hi and welcom to SO. The way you are trying to generate a filename or in other word string variable is no right, try something like `filename=sprintf('%d.xlsx',k)`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message you provided and the format `(k,'%dtrf.xlsx')`, your loop should probably be something like:

```
data=cell([5 1]);
for k=101:105
  filename=sprintf('%dtrf.xlsx',k);
  data{k-100} = readmatrix(filename,'Range','BS:BX');
end
```

where `BS`, `BX` are assumed to be valid column names in your .xlsx files.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment, I forgot to add that the exact name of my xlsx files are "101trf.xlsx" hence why trf is in the for loop. It ran without an error but my workspace doesn't have any data now. It has data which is a 5x1 cell, filename which is 105trf.xlsx and k which is 105.

Comment: You can type `data{1}` to see the data that were read from the first file, `data{2}` for the second file, and so on.